# Webapp call to request.get() changes contents of request.body

Tags: google-app-engine, web-applications

I'm using webapp with Google App Engine.

I recently added a call to `request.get('variable_name')`.  This worked fine, but completely changed the contents of `request.body`.

Upon closer examination, it looks like if I do not make a call to `request.get()`, then `request.body` yields text without any url formatting.  But after a call the `request.get()`, `request.body` now contains text that includes URL formatting (a lot of '%' signs, etc...).

Am I using webapp wrong?  should I not be mixing and matching these two methods for information retrieval?

**Here is some sample code:**

```
class profiles_resource(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        # Value of request.body in debugger: 'str: {"query":"SELECT..."
        token = self.request.get('token')
        # Value of request.body in debugger: '%7B%22query%22%3A%22SELECT..."
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`request.get` looks for request parameters in both the query string and the body of the request, assuming the body is formencoded. If you intend to read the body directly, do not use `self.request.get` or `self.request.POST`.

Comment: So a call to request.get may change the contents of request.body?

Comment: @DutrowLLC Possibly. It doesn't generally make sense to access both - why do you need to?

Comment: I have a JSON structure in the body.  So I just take the whole body and turn it into a dictionary object.  Then there are key-value pairs coming in through the URL that have a different purpose.

Comment: @DutrowLLC Use `self.request.GET` to access query string parameters, and `self.request.body` to access the post body.

Comment: @Nick_Johnson Ah, so I should use the capital 'GET' which is a dictionary object instead of the lowercase 'get()' function.

Comment: @DutrowLLC Correct. `get()` is just a convenience method that fetches from either POST body or query parameters.